# What regular expression do I need to check for some non-latin characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am checking a field if it is Latin Characters or not.

```
var foreignCharacters = $("#foreign_characters").val();
var rlatins = /[\u0000-\u007f]/;

if (rlatins.test(foreignCharacters)) {
  alert("This is Latin Characters");
} else {
  alert("This is non-latin Characters");    
}
```

This works well, but I would like to change it so when I enter any non-latin characters, such as chinese characters, along with a space(which is within that range I am using currently) it will still say it is non-latin characters.

How can I change the regular expression I have to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just test for the presence of non-ascii characters instead of testing for the presence of ascii characters:

```
var foreignCharacters = $("#foreign_characters").val();
var rforeign = /[^\u0000-\u007f]/;

if (rforeign.test(foreignCharacters)) {
  alert("This is non-Latin Characters");
} else {
  alert("This is Latin Characters");    
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea! Thanks! I'm getting this error when trying to use that regex in php: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 2

Comment: Different syntax in PHP: Try `/[\x{0000}-\x{007f}]/u`

Comment: it says that the German `Prüfung` is non-latin chars

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the entire string use (in php)

```
preg_match('/^[\x{0000}-\x{007F}]*$/u',$s);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to making your own regex with code point ranges is to use the [xregexp library](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp)

Some examples from the documentation:

```
XRegExp('^\\p{Hiragana}+$').test('ひらがな'); // -> true
XRegExp('^[\\p{Latin}\\p{Common}]+$').test('Über Café.'); // -> true
```