# How to Detect Non "GSM 7 bit alphabet" characters in input field

Tags: javascript, regex, gsm

I am trying to detect if a text input field has any character that doesn't belong to the GSM 7 bit alphabet. The table with the characters is here http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/default_alphabet.html

After a lot of searching I found this ([What regular expression do I need to check for some non-latin characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550951/what-regular-expression-do-i-need-to-check-for-some-non-latin-characters)) that its pretty close to what I want to accomplish because It detects Non latin characters. How can I alter the regular expression to include the GSM 7 bit alphabet?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test foreign chars</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="foreign_characters" size="12" type="text" name="foreign_characters" value="test">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){

    $('#foreign_characters').on("keyup", function(){

        var foreignCharacters = $("#foreign_characters").val();
        var rforeign = /[^\u0000-\u007f]/;

        if (rforeign.test(foreignCharacters)) {
          alert("This is non-Latin Characters");
        } else {
          alert("This is Latin Characters");
        }

    });

})();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put all valid characters in a string and then search the string repeatedly.

```
gsm = "@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞ^{}\[~]|€ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà";
var letter = 'a';
var letterInAlfabet = gsm.indexOf(letter) !== -1;
```

Make sure you get your encodings right if you use this, i.e. **save your Javascript file as UTF8 and specify that it is UTF8 to the browser**.

Comment: I'll check it right now cause the regex is not working for me.

Comment: So I have to check all characters one by one against this gsm variable?

Comment: Can you please respond? the letter "A" returns true, the string "AD" returns false. As I understand I have to loop each character and check against the gsm string. How can I do that?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { letter = str[i]; }`

Comment: You are missing a space and newline characters.

Comment: Please note that, `^{}\[~]|€` this characters are being treated as 2 characters.

Comment: why is there uppercase Ç but not lowercase ç ?

Answer (score 24):

```
function isGSMAlphabet(text) {
    var regexp = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|\u20AC]*$");

    return regexp.test(text);
}
```

This regular expression should solve your problem.

Comment: I am putting rforeign = "^[A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|\u20AC]*$"; and I get an error of "rforeign.test is not a function "

Comment: The regex is OK, but you are using it wrong. Use either `var rforeign = /regex/;` or `var rforeign = new RegExp("regex");`.

Comment: Yes, Sjoerd is right, you can't assign this regex value inside quotes, you have to assign it inside slashes or, if you want to use quotes you just have to instantiate a RegExp.

Comment: Yes few minutes ago I figure it out and used new RegExp() but I put characters that should be FALSE and they aren't. I'll keep looking.

Comment: This does work in javascript. Code used:     function containsAllAscii(str) {
        return  /^[A-Za-z0-9\r\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!"#$%&amp;'()*+,\-./:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\[~\]|\u20AC]*$/.test(str) ;
    }

Comment: the regex is missing char \u00A4

Comment: What's the purpose of the triple escaped backslash `\\\\\\\`?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answers will work, but they suffer from complexity (using a regex) and performance (needing to search through two arrays). Here's a solution that will perform better, due to the use of a lookup Set, and a loop which will short-circuit if a non-GSM7 character is found. Unicode points are used so that different character encodings are not a problem when cutting and pasting this code.

```js
const gsmCodePoints = new Set([
  0x000a, 0x000c, 0x000d, 
  0x0020, 0x0021, 0x0022, 0x0023, 0x0024, 0x0025, 0x0026, 0x0027, 0x0028, 0x0029, 0x002a, 0x002b, 0x002c, 0x002d, 0x002e, 0x002f,
  0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0032, 0x0033, 0x0034, 0x0035, 0x0036, 0x0037, 0x0038, 0x0039, 0x003a, 0x003b, 0x003c, 0x003d, 0x003e, 0x003f,
  0x0040, 0x0041, 0x0042, 0x0043, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0046, 0x0047, 0x0048, 0x0049, 0x004a, 0x004b, 0x004c, 0x004d,
  0x004e, 0x004f,
  0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053, 0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056, 0x0057, 0x0058, 0x0059,  0x005a, 0x005b, 0x005c, 0x005d, 0x005e, 0x005f, 
  0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x006a, 0x006b, 0x006c, 0x006d, 0x006e, 0x006f, 
  0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078, 0x0079, 0x007a, 0x007b, 0x007c, 0x007d, 0x007e,
  0x00a1, 0x00a3, 0x00a4, 0x00a5, 0x00a7,
  0x00bf,
  0x00c4, 0x00c5, 0x00c6, 0x00c7, 0x00c9,
  0x00d1, 0x00d6, 0x00d8, 0x00dc, 0x00df,
  0x00e0, 0x00e4, 0x00e5, 0x00e6, 0x00e8, 0x00e9, 0x00ec,
  0x00f1, 0x00f2, 0x00f6, 0x00f8, 0x00f9, 0x00fc,
  0x0393, 0x0394, 0x0398, 0x039b, 0x039e, 0x03a0, 0x03a3, 0x03a6, 0x03a8, 0x03a9,
  0x20ac,
]);

function isGsmMessage(message) {
  for (const s of message) {
    const codePoint = s.codePointAt(0);
    if (codePoint && !gsmCodePoints.has(codePoint)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

isGsmMessage('foo'); // -> true
isGsmMessage('⚡️ bar '); // -> false

// All GSM characters
isGsmMessage('@£$¥èéùìòÇ\nØø\rÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ\x20!"#¤%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà\f^{}\\[~]|€'); // -> true
```

Comment: Kudos for using codes instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I have `textarea` with id `smscontent`. I use below regex/code

```
$('#smscontent').on('input, change keyup', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \r\n@£$¥!\"#$%&amp;'\(\)*\+,_.\/:;&lt;=&gt;?^{}\\\[~\]]*/ig, ''));
});
```

To test the regex shared by Lajos - https://www.regextester.com/99623

To test the regex used in this answer - https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106436