# Regex to replace non GSM-7 characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm modifing the GSM-7 set from a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12673229/761793) - it's written for Javascript, but I'm modifying it to work with `preg`.

I added a delimiter `~`, [converted the `\u` to `\x{XXXX}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538296/761793), and added `u` to the end. I also added `^` after the opening bracket `[` so [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would replace anything that is NOT a GSM-7 character with a blank.

My problem is that [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is correctly returning false, but preg_replace isn't replacing anything.

What am I missing? I've tried adding parentheses right after and before the `~`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

The code below shows just the garbled text, instead of the garbled portions being replaced with a blank by preg_replace.

**Edit:** I've also tried `$gsmchars = '~^[^A-Za-z0-9]*$~u';` which preg_replace does the same thing - nothing. What option am I missing in my regex?

```
$gsmchars = '~^[^A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\x{0394}_\x{03A6}\x{0393}\x{039B}\x{03A9}\x{03A0}\x{03A8}\x{03A3}\x{0398}\x{039E}ÆæßÉ!\"#$%&amp;\'\(\)*+,\\-./:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[\~\\]|\x{20AC}]*$~u';

$string = 'ab€m²cdefلg123$';

$match = preg_match($gsmchars, $string);

if ($match === false) {
    die("ERROR");
} else if (!$match) {
    $replace = preg_replace($gsmchars, '', $string);
    //Now that it's in UTF-8, replace the non-GSM chars
    die($replace . "A");    
} else {
    die('match');
}
```

Comment: `preg_replace` replaces what it matches. If it doesn't match anything, it doesn't replace anything.

Comment: @S.Ahn I understand that - but preg_match returns 0, indicating `preg` realizes there are non-GSM characters. preg_replace should then find those and replace them with the empty string.

Comment: `preg_match` would find them if you told it to look for them, but you aren't. Again, from the documentation: "If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred."

Comment: @S.Ahn Since the string does in fact contain characters that are NOT in `$gsmchars`, and `preg_replace` isn't matching on them, what am I missing in my regex? That's my question :)

Comment: @S.Ahn See my edit. I made the regex simpler, and preg_replace still won't replace the chars that aren't in `$gsmchars`. I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused. I think I have the answer.

Comment: @S.Ahn I saw you posted a solution, but it's gone now - it seemed to (mostly) work, it just seemed to be taking out more characters than it should. Why'd you remove it?

Comment: It didn't work fully. It's back now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$gsmchars = '~[^A-Za-z0-9 \r\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\x{0394}_\x{03A6}\x{0393}\x{039B}\x{03A9}\x{03A0}\x{03A8}\x{03A3}\x{0398}\x{039E}ÆæßÉ!\"#$%&\'\(\)*+,\-.\/:;<=>;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\[\~\]\|\x{20AC}\\]~u'; // added backslash

$string = 'ab€m²cdefلg123$';
echo preg_replace($gsmchars, '', $string);

$match = preg_match($gsmchars, $string);

if ($match === false) {
    die("ERROR");
} else if ($match) {
    $replace = preg_replace($gsmchars, '', $string);
    //Now that it's in UTF-8, replace the non-GSM chars
    die($replace . "A");
} else {
    die('match');
}
```

This site really helps debug regular expressions:

```
http://regex101.com
```

You also need to change your `if-else` to proceed with the `preg_replace` when there **is** a match.

Comment: The `if-else` was just a test case. This looks like it is working perfectly, thank you! Looks like the version I had was pretty nasty when it came to trying to match some of these characters. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is missing the \u00A4 char ?