# GSM and UTF string detection

Tags: python-3.x, gsm, utf

Is there any way to detect whether in a String,all characters corresponds to GSM/UTF/Both characters set??I am working on Python-3,and I need to know,if there exists any encoding method,by which i could decide all the characters correspond to that String are GSM/UTF/combination of both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Detect Non "GSM 7 bit alphabet" characters in input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673120/how-to-detect-non-gsm-7-bit-alphabet-characters-in-input-field)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673120/how-to-detect-non-gsm-7-bit-alphabet-characters-in-input-field. Regular expression is probably the best bet to solve this problem.