# NodeJS: Check that a string contains only GSM 03.38 characters

Tags: node.js, encoding, gsm

Given a string I want to make sure it only contains chars allowed by [GSM 03.38 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38).
should I check it manually or there is a smarter way/exiting lib to do it?

Comment: You can use regex. Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673120/how-to-detect-non-gsm-7-bit-alphabet-characters-in-input-field

Comment: @Sami thanks but i was wondering if there is something internal in Node or maybe some official package. Because if my question was about a popular encoding like UTF8 there are tons of ready stuff