# Detect Language type in edittext android Pie?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, counter

I want to detect which language typed by user in edit text like Hindi or English because I am making an app like SMS app and here I am making a text counter which works according to edittext language type thats mean if language is English Counter Shows 160 character or language is Hindi counter shows 60 character.I am able to make custom counter with the help of textwatcher but here I am unable to detect a language of edit text.

***I tried:***

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
        String localeString = ims.getLocale();
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
        String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

but it gives nothing in Logcat.
and when I am using this.

```
Log.d(TAG, "messageTYPE: " + Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
```

It shows only english everytime while I am entering Hindi cahracter.

**What do I want?**

If I am able to detect language type than I can make a custom counter for edit text.

**OR**

Is there any way to make edit text like message app which is automatically detect language type and set counter according language.

Please Help me guys, Thanks In advance.

**UPDATE**

```
if(s.length() < 160 || s.length() == 160){
            if (s.length()/160 == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "length160 " + s.length());
                Log.d(TAG, "length160 " + (160-s.length()));
                textViewCounter.setText((160 - s.length()) + "/" + "1");
                messageCount =1;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length160: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (s.length()/160 == 1){
                textViewCounter.setText((160 - s.length()) + "/" + "1");
                messageCount =1;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length1602: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if (s.length() > 160 && s.length() <= 305){
//          textViewCounter.setText((305 - s.length()) + "/" + "2");
//          messageCount = s.length()/160;
//          Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "above " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (s.length()/305 == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "length305 " + s.length());
                Log.d(TAG, "length305 " + (305-s.length()));
                textViewCounter.setText((305 - s.length()) + "/" + "2");
                messageCount = 2;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length305: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (s.length()/305 == 1){
                textViewCounter.setText((305 - s.length()) + "/" + "2");
                messageCount = 2;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length3052: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if (s.length() > 305 && s.length() <= 459){
//                                        textViewCounter.setText((305 - s.length()) + "/" + "2");
//                                        messageCount = s.length()/160;
//                                        Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "above " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (s.length()/459 == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "length459 " + s.length());
                Log.d(TAG, "length459 " + (459-s.length()));
                textViewCounter.setText((459 - s.length()) + "/" + "3");
                messageCount = 3;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length459: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (s.length()/305 == 1){
                textViewCounter.setText((459 - s.length()) + "/" + "3");
                messageCount = 3;
                Toast.makeText(SendingActivity.this, "length4592: " + messageCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

This is custom counter for counting words and make like message app.

Comment: SMS size limit is 140 bytes. You could check for characters that do not belong to 7-bit GSM encoding (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673120/how-to-detect-non-gsm-7-bit-alphabet-characters-in-input-field)), and change the character limit accordingly.

Comment: I am unable to relate your answer to my question.

Comment: You a trying to detect the keyboard language. But what happens if the keyboard is English but user pastes some Hindi text? I think that the counter should show 160 if the text is in 7-bit GSM encoding, and 70 if not.

Comment: Can you Help me how to implement that logic.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SmsMessage.calculateLength()` (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean))) to calculate the number of remaining characters:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int[] result = SmsMessage.calculateLength(s, false);
            textViewCounter.setText("" + result[2] + "/" + result[0]);
            messageCount = result[0];
            Log.i("TAG", "Characters: " + result[1] + "/" + (result[1] + result[2]));
            Log.i("TAG", "Number of SMS's: " + result[0]);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: does it set counter according to language??

Comment: Yes. `result[1] + result[2]` is 160 if `editText` contains only English characters, and 70 if it contains other characters (Hindi, Cyrillic, etc.)

Comment: can you help me on more thing ? If yes so I will update my answer.

Comment: Can you describe me what is result[1] and result[2]

Comment: result[1] the number of code units used, and result[2] is the number of code units remaining until the next message (see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength(java.lang.String,%2520boolean))). The sum `result[1] + result[2]` is then the total number of characters per message (it is 160 or 70 depending on text).

Comment: can you see my update answer. I want with implement my update question with your answer . How can i do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193312/discussion-between-atarasenko-and-blackblind).

Comment: I have answered in chat